# How should i approach refracting the badly written Reverse Polish Notation java code in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I'm having difficulty knowing where to start when it comes to refactoring the following badly written Reverse Polish Notation in Eclipse. And would like to know where to start in general when trying to refactoring code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class StackNode 
{
    public StackNode(double data, StackNode underneath) 
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.underneath = underneath;
    }

    public StackNode underneath;
    public double data;
}


class RPN 
{
    public void into(double new_data) 
    {
        StackNode new_node = new StackNode(new_data, top);
        top = new_node;
    }

    public double outof( ) 
    {
        double top_data = top.data;
        top = top.underneath;
        return top_data;
    }

    public RPN(String command) 
    {
        top = null;
        this.command = command;
    }

    public double get( ) 
    {
        double a, b;
        int j;

        for(int i = 0; i < command.length( ); i++) 
        {
            // if it's a digit
            if(Character.isDigit(command.charAt(i))) 
            {
                double number;

                // get a string of the number
                String temp = "";
                for(j = 0; (j < 100) && (Character.isDigit(command.charAt(i)) || (command.charAt(i) == '.')); j++, i++) 
                {
                    temp = temp + String.valueOf(command.charAt(i));
                }

                // convert to double and add to the stack
                number = Double.parseDouble(temp);
                into(number);
                } else if(command.charAt(i) == '+') {
                    b = outof( );
                    a = outof( );
                    into(a + b);
                } else if(command.charAt(i) == '-') {
                    b = outof( );
                    a = outof( );
                    into(a - b);
                } else if(command.charAt(i) == '*') {
                    b = outof( );
                    a = outof( );
                    into(a * b);
                } else if(command.charAt(i) == '/') {
                    b = outof( );
                    a = outof( );
                    into(a / b);
                } else if(command.charAt(i) == '^') {
                    b = outof( );
                    a = outof( );
                    into(Math.pow(a, b));
                } else if(command.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException( );
            }
        }

        double val = outof( );
        if(top != null) 
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( );
        }

        return val;
    }

    private String command;
    private StackNode top;

    /* main method */
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter RPN expression or \"quit\".");
            String line = input.nextLine( );
            if(line.equals("quit")) 
            {
                input.close();
                break;
            } else {
                RPN calc = new RPN(line);
                System.out.printf("Answer is %f\n", calc.get( ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anything would help thanks.
P.S. Sorry for the long code i couldn't make it any shorter.

Comment: Questions for improving otherwise working code may be a better fit on [codereview.se], but be sure to follow their acceptable content guidelines.

Comment: Start with the part (or parts) you think are "badly written".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SonarLint(Eclipse extension)](https://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/) that helps you detect and fix quality issues as you write code. You can download it from [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint).